# Is there any way of fetching the value of a key in remote JSON file, without downloading the whole HUGE JSON file?

Tags: android, json

I am a beginner in android development. I am on developing a dictionary app. The problem is quite obvious. I don't want the whole JSON file to be downloaded. I just want to send a key(a word in this case) and get its value(the meaning of that word) from the remote JSON. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your server to support this sort of request, such as supporting a particular URL to retrieve values for a given key.

Comment: Ok, so is there no other way than modifying the server?